# What am I doing wrong with this python find() method?

Tags: python, find

```
import urllib2,cookielib

site= "https://www.google.com/search?q=buddha&source=lnms&tbm=isch'"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = page.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    content = e.fp.read()
#content = page.read()
print content

imgstart = 1
while imgstart > 1:
    start = imgstart+1
    imgstart = content.find(',"ou":"',start)
    #print imgstart
    imgend = content.find('","ow":',imgstart+1)
    #print imgend
    imgurl = content[imgstart+7:imgend]
    print imgurl
```

If I copy the printed content into Notepad++, I can easily find ',"ou":"' but for some reason my `content.find` method cannot.

Comment: `start` and `imgstart` are integers, not strings. You might want to look into the page content instead

Comment: doesn't find return integers? I am expecting them to be integers

Comment: hey, somebody just edited the code and now it correctly says `content.find`, instead of `start.find`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. The first being that you are never entering your while loop:

You have set `imgstart = 1`, so you will never enter the loop.

set this instead:

```
while imgstart >= 1:
```

However, your next problem is that you have an infinite loop because you are incrementing imgstart in your loop. I am not sure what your intention is with this incrementer, but you need to ensure you have an exit condition.

Based on the code provided, I managed to get it to run, however, I did have to modify it slightly to make sure it ended.

I changed the while loop to only run for 10 iterations to get some kind of sample. Some of the data came back as the full markup, which I don't think you want, but there were URLs there. So you might want to look up your matchers to make sure you have your matching set correctly.

```
imgstart = 1
i = 0
#while imgstart >= 1:
while i <= 10:
    start = imgstart+1
    imgstart = content.find(',"ou":"', start)
    imgend = content.find('","ow":', imgstart + 1)
    imgurl = content[imgstart+7:imgend]
    print imgurl
    i += 1
```

Comment: really? i wonder why it's not running on mine then. well it just prints the content it doesn't print the imageurl like i exptected.

Comment: okay, i got it running but i i expected to see more than 7 results, should be hundreds (at least that's what i see when i load the page manually from a browser).

Comment: @TinTran I've updated with the code that I managed to get running, let me know if you have any questions about it we can go over it.

Comment: nice your code solved it i just gotta check to see if i <= 1000

Comment: Thanks a lot I have been playing with this for like an hour

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the `while` loop because `imgstart == 1` in the beginning